# After create-react-app eject appHtml is not copied

Tags: javascript, webpack, create-react-app

Does someone have an idea, why does after ejecting in create-react-app creates in build.js a filter for `appHtml`?

```
function copyPublicFolder() {
  fs.copySync(paths.appPublic, paths.appBuild, {
    dereference: true,
    filter: file => file !== paths.appHtml,
  });
}
```

I did eject because for me the `appHtml` (public/index.html) is not the entry point for my react app and I needed to change the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` parts in `webpack.config.js`. But now I see this filtering and because of this my `index.html` is not copied over into the `build` dir, but I want to know if this will have any other effect on my app?!

Answer (score 0):

I found your question a year later. Let me know if you've solved it since. My workaround was changing the `scripts.build` value in `package.json`. See below:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js && mv build/index.html build/testpage.html",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js"
  }
```

Edit: "I found your question a few years later", haha!